# Store printed results in a dataframe in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, yahoo-finance

I start using Python, I have a code which get information of stocks from Yahoo. I would like to store this data in a dataframe.

```
yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(assets)

print(yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data("2013-01-01", "2021-01-30", "daily"))
print(yahoo_financials.get_currency())
print(yahoo_financials.get_pe_ratio())
print(yahoo_financials.get_price_to_sales())
```

This code works, now I would like to store this data in a dataframe.

```
#Create a dataframe to store the relevant data
df3 = pd.DataFrame(YahooFinancials(assets))
```

I want to store the data in pyhton, in a table, in order to analyse the data. The output from the print code is difficult to read. So the idea is not export the data to excel for now. The idea is to show the name of the assets, the pe ratio, the price to sales ratio,the currency, and the adjusted close price per day in a dataframe (table form). I don't think I can see the historical PE ratio or the price to sales ratio, which is not an issue.
I receive now a error, ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post a sample of YahooFinancials(assets)

Comment: !pip install yahoofinancials;
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials ;                                                      
 assets =  ["FB", "AMZN", "AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOG"]

Comment: That only specifies the issue, so we need to take action.`ratio = pd.DataFrame(yahoo_financials.get_pe_ratio(), index=[0])`

Comment: I want to store the data in pyhton, in a table, in order to analyse the data. The output from the print code is difficult to read. So the idea is not export the data to excel for now. The idea is to show the name of the assets, the pe ratio, the price to sales ratio,the currency, and the adjusted close price per day in a dataframe (table form). I don't think I can see the historical PE ratio or the price to sales ratio, which is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section describes the steps to turn each data into a data frame. The return value of this library is in JSON format, so we need to convert it into a data frame.

1. Convert price data(FB)

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
assets = ["FB", "AMZN", "AAPL", "NFLX", "GOOG"]

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(assets)

daily = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data("2021-01-01", "2021-01-30", "daily")

df = pd.read_json(str(daily).replace("'", '"'), orient='records')

    FB  AMZN    AAPL    NFLX    GOOG
eventsData  {}  {}  {}  {}  {}
firstTradeDate  {'formatted_date': '2012-05-18', 'date': 13373...   {'formatted_date': '1997-05-15', 'date': 86370...   {'formatted_date': '1980-12-12', 'date': 34547...   {'formatted_date': '2002-05-23', 'date': 10221...   {'formatted_date': '2004-08-19', 'date': 10929...
currency    USD     USD     USD     USD     USD
instrumentType  EQUITY  EQUITY  EQUITY  EQUITY  EQUITY
timeZone    {'gmtOffset': -18000}   {'gmtOffset': -18000}   {'gmtOffset': -18000}   {'gmtOffset': -18000}   {'gmtOffset': -18000}
prices  [{'date': 1609770600, 'high': 275.0, 'low': 26...   [{'date': 1609770600, 'high': 3272.0, 'low': 3...   [{'date': 1609770600, 'high': 133.610000610351...   [{'date': 1609770600, 'high': 540.799987792968...   [{'date': 1609770600, 'high': 1760.65002441406...

fb_df = pd.DataFrame(df.loc['prices', 'FB'])

fb_df.head()
    date    high    low     open    close   volume  adjclose    formatted_date
0   1609770600  275.000000  265.200012  274.779999  268.940002  15106100    268.940002  2021-01-04
1   1609857000  272.399994  268.209991  268.290009  270.970001  9871600     270.970001  2021-01-05
2   1609943400  267.750000  260.010010  262.000000  263.309998  24354100    263.309998  2021-01-06
3   1610029800  271.609985  264.779999  265.899994  268.739990  15789800    268.739990  2021-01-07
4   1610116200  268.950012  263.179993  268.309998  267.570007  18512500    267.570007  2021-01-08
```

2. Convert investment information

```
per_ratio = yahoo_financials.get_pe_ratio()
per_ratio.update({'idx':'ratio'})
ratio = pd.DataFrame(per_ratio, index=[0])

currency = yahoo_financials.get_currency()
currency.update({'idx':'currency'})
curr = pd.DataFrame(currency, index=[1])

volume = yahoo_financials.get_price_to_sales()
volume.update({'idx':'volume'})
vol =pd.DataFrame(volume, index=[2])

ratio
    FB  AMZN    AAPL    NFLX    GOOG    idx
0   25.602575   93.74306    35.79062    87.56415    35.471867   ratio

currency
    FB  AMZN    AAPL    NFLX    GOOG    idx
1   USD     USD     USD     USD     USD     currency

volume
    FB  AMZN    AAPL    NFLX    GOOG    idx
2   8.55742     4.623472    7.531772    9.433204    7.214964    volume
```

You can also combine investment information into a single data frame. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As of my understanding, YahooFinancials() returns a json string.
If that's true you can use pandas.read_json(json_str)

something like this would work:

```
yahoo = pd.read_json(YahooFinancials(assets))
yahoo.to_csv("your_path.csv")
```

(I haven't run the code, but the basic idea is correct)

check [pandas document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) for more